# How can I pass Go arrays to C?

Tags: go

I was struggling with OpenGL ES. It didn't worked well.
And I got similar thing working in C.(I just copied Go code and modified(syntax) and removed(non-important function call) some things for C.)

I finally found that Go arrays were not passed to C function.(So, arrays as vertex array, indices couldn't be passed well and did something wrong when I render.)

I tested with this code:

C function part:

```
void passTest(void *Ptr){
    int *test = (GLfloat *)Ptr;
    printf("C: test=%p\n", test);
    printf("C: test[0]=%d\ntest[1]=%d\ntest[2]=%d\ntest[3]=%d\n", test[0], test[1], test[2], test[3]);
}
```

And this is Go part:

```
test := []int{ 0, 3, 9, 81018 }
var ptr unsafe.Pointer = (unsafe.Pointer)(&test)
fmt.Printf("Go: test=%p\n", ptr)
fmt.Printf("Go: test[0]=%d\ntest[1]=%d\ntest[2]=%d\ntest[3]=%d\n", test[0], test[1], test[2], test[3])
C.passTest(ptr)
```

Result is:

```
Go: test=0x10300010
Go: test[0]=0
test[1]=3
test[2]=9
test[3]=81018
C: test=0x10300010
C: test[0]=271581216
test[1]=4
test[2]=4
test[3]=0
```

As you can see, pointer value passed well. But, printed value is wrong.
Am I doing something wrong with passing arrays to C?

Comment: You're passing a slice of `int` (which might be an int32 or int64 depending on the system), and interpreting them as `GLfloat`. Because you're using `unsafe` you need to be absolutely sure your types match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct for an array, but here you have a go slice. Use the address of the first element to get the address of the underlying array

```
ptr := unsafe.Pointer(&test[0])
```